# What's the difference between GNOME Remix and GNOME Shell?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension

I'm asking this because I had problems with Gnome Shell (i.e.: the apps menu disappeared, GNOME 3.6 version changed to GNOME 2, weird stuff...)

Answer (score 0):

[Ubuntu GNOME Remix](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGNOME/ReleaseNotes/12.10) is the Ubuntu base with Gnome Shell on top (instead of Unity).